# heroku account was suspended cause violate the Use Policy

Tags: heroku

1. My account was suspend and received a email which says I violence the Use Policy.
   [Notification email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hluPQ.png)
2. I sent the email to the email address which written on the last photo, and received the email following.
   [the second email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwHQm.png)
3. At first, I reply and received the reply on below.[the third email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8ZLK.png)
4. But I can't view my ticket and can't update anymore cause my account was suspended. I reply the email but they don't reply anymore.
5. So, I do these all again, but I didn't received anything news after received the second email.[the second email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwHQm.png)
   How can I do to restore my account?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a Heroku support issue

Comment: I am sorry but I can't contract the help center on Heroku. I wrote many emails to them but didn't reply. Also, they suggest me to find help there on their help page.

Comment: I sympathize with your plight, but surely they are referring to technical questions. Please see the [help center -- on topic section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) which says: "Questions asking for customer support with third-party services (such as App Stores) are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Instead, please direct your questions to the relevant company/organisation's technical support team." You need a Heroku representative to restore your account. If they don't respond to your emails, I'm afraid there's not much we can do for you to reinstate your account.

Comment: Yep, but actually, I create a new ticket on my new account two days ago, but they didn't reply to anything until now. And I will remain this question until they reply to me at least.